# Power Automate Query Filter not valid but result matches

Tags: power-automate

I've got a flow that pulls data from a powerbi dataset, initializes that as a variable, then within an Apply to each, I use Get items to pull a SharePoint list. I'm trying to filter the SharePoint list down to just those records that have a match in the powerbi dataset. After testing the flow, I get a 'query not valid' error, but the populated filter query looks correct to me. Any ideas of how to get the query to run?

Here are the expressions

[image]

And here's the error

[image]

I've tried setting both sides to integers and strings, but no change.